# Cross Communication Between Objects within an Object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

Forgive me if this has been answered before, but my searching has yielded no results. This is likely because I lack the terminology needed.

I have been working on a text based RPG as a side project and have been experimenting with `closures` in `JavaScript`. Below is a very basic example of what I am trying to accomplish:

**app.js**

```
var app = {};
```

This is where everything will be mounted to preserve `namespace`.

**character.js**

```
app.character = (function() {
  // the character manipulation object
  // this will be used to create character objects
  function _createCharacter(name) {
    return {
      // Just an example
      name: name,
      stats: { health: 10, level: 1 },
      weapon: {}
    };
  }
  return {
    createCharacter: _createCharacter
  };
})();
```

The character object is pretty straightforward, but what gets tricky is this next part.

**items.js**

```
app.items = {};
```

The items object will hold other objects; one for each item type because they all behave differently. The types will be: `gear`, `consumable`, `quest`. For simplicity I have only included gear.

**gear.js**

```
app.items.gear = (function() {
  // the gear manipulation object
  // this will be used to create gear objects
  function _createGear() {
    return {
      name: 'Sword',
      mods: { damage: 3, strength: 1 } // In reality it's random
    };
  }
  return {
    createGear: _createGear
  };
})();
```

So this object is two objects deep on the `app` object.

**game.js**

```
app.game = (function() {
    var _player = {};
    // closed functions in this area
    function _giveWeapon() {
      _player.weapon = this.item.gear.createGear();
    }
    function _newPlayer(name) {
      _player = this.character.createCharacter(name);
      _giveWeapon();
    }
    function getPlayer() {
      return _player;
    }
    return {
      getPlayer: _getPlayer,
      newPlayer: _newPlayer
    };
})();
```

This is the object that will pilot the game, i.e. call to other objects for functions as needed.

**int.js**

```
app.game.newPlayer('Ryan');
// should create { name: 'Ryan', stats: { health: 10, level: 1 }, weapon {} under game._player
```

This simply starts the game.

When ran it creates an error before anything even gets off the ground, because the `game` object can't see `items.gear` or `character` objects and returns them as `undefined`. What I am trying to get to is having them all able to communicate with one another inside the `app` object while remaining closures. Also, any advice on building single namespace complex JavaScript apps would be extremely helpful.

Comment: what environment are you running this in?  Browser? Node?

Comment: Oops, let that bit out. This is front end, so browser side.

Comment: That means the order in which these scripts are ran is important.  So please provide a jsfiddle (or whatever js playground fits your fancy)

Comment: Sure thing! Here is the jsbin I have create. I like jsbin because it provides a console. http://jsbin.com/vucibupixa/edit?js,console

Comment: Your issue is this:

this.character.createCharacter(name);

`this` refers to `app.game` when you are expecting `this` to refer to `app`.  I'll write a solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I modified a few functional points, and a few aesthetic ones.

**functional**
 - pass the app object into your `game` closure and use it instead of `this`
 - change `theApp.item.gear` -> `theApp.items.gear`

**aesthetic**
 - use function hoisting to create more skimmable code.  Init your closure with the necessary variables, then return your api.  After that you can declare your functions which only need to be referenced if detail is needed.

I can't help much with namespace principles since I avoided them in favor of bundlers and 'require' or more recently 'import' statements.

```js
var app = {};

app.character = (function() {
  return {
    createCharacter: _createCharacter
  };

  // the character manipulation object
  // this will be used to create character objects
  function _createCharacter(name) {
    return {
      // Just an example
      name: name,
      stats: { health: 10, level: 1 },
      weapon: {}
    };
  }
})();

app.items = {};

app.items.gear = (function() {
  return {
    createGear: _createGear
  };

  // the gear manipulation object
  // this will be used to create gear objects
  function _createGear() {
    return {
      name: 'Sword',
      mods: { damage: 3, strength: 1 } // In reality it's random
    };
  }
})();

app.game = (function(theApp) {
  var _player = {};

  return {
    getPlayer: _getPlayer,
    createPlayer: _createPlayer
  };

  // closed functions in this area
  function _giveWeapon() {
    _player.weapon = theApp.items.gear.createGear();
  }
  function _createPlayer(name) {
    _player = theApp.character.createCharacter(name);
    _giveWeapon();
  }
  function _getPlayer() {
    return _player;
  }
})(app);

// should create { name: 'Ryan', stats: { health: 10, level: 1 }, weapon {} under game._player
app.game.createPlayer('Ryan');
var ryan = JSON.stringify(app.game.getPlayer(), null, 2);
document.getElementById('ryan').innerHTML = ryan;
```

```html
<pre id="ryan"></pre>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know you could do that in a IIFE! Awesome! Thanks! Yeah I want to look into RequireJS in the future. Right now I am just feeling out how I want to construct apps. Thanks again!

Comment: Good approach.  It's very easy to overwhelm yourself with tools/libs/frameworks/languages/blaaaaaaa.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Below code should get you going:

Basically, the reason why your code was not working earlier was that when you hit this line `this.character.createCharacter(name);`, the binding to `this` is with game but game object doesn't contain `chatacter` object.
Similar logic applis to the line `this.item.gear.createGear();`.

```js
var app = {};

    app.character = (function() {
        // the character manipulation object
        // this will be used to create character objects
        function _createCharacter(name) {
            return {
                // Just an example
                name: name,
                stats: { health: 10, level: 1 },
                weapon: {}
            };
        }
        return {
            createCharacter: _createCharacter
        };
    })();

    app.items = {};

    app.items.gear = (function() {
        // the gear manipulation object
        // this will be used to create gear objects
        function _createGear() {
            return {
                name: 'Sword',
                mods: { damage: 3, strength: 1 } // In reality it's random
            };
        }
        return {
            createGear: _createGear
        };
    })();

    app.game = (function() {
        var _player = {};
        //this.character = character;
        // closed functions in this area
        function _giveWeapon() {
            _player.weapon = app.items.gear.createGear();
        }
        function _newPlayer(name) {
            //_player = this.character.createCharacter(name);
            _player = app.character.createCharacter(name);
            
            _giveWeapon();
        }
        function _getPlayer() {
            return _player;
        }
        return {
            getPlayer: _getPlayer,
            newPlayer: _newPlayer
        };
    })();
    
    app.game.newPlayer('Ryan');
    console.log(app.game.getPlayer());
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!